# retornar mayusculas mediante prototype sin funcion

Tags: javascript, string, funciones, this

para editar los prototypes de String se necesita una funcion ya que ponerla en una variable se pondra en
undefined

```
//muestra a this con el valor de variable
String.prototype.mayuscula = function(){ return this.toUpperCase() };
//muestra el valor de this en NaN
String.prototype.mayuscula =this.toUpperCase();

var p="hola";
alert(p.mayuscula());//muestra HOLA
alert(p.mayuscula);//muestra undefined
```

y mi pregunta es. ¿como hago que llame a la funcion sin necesidad de los parentesis ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo podrías solucionar utilizando el [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) de objetos de `javascript`:

Donde el objeto al que le vamos a definir una propiedad sería el `prototype` de `String`, su nombre sería `mayusculas` y su `descriptor` tendría el método `get` para devolver automáticamente el valor de la instancia (que en este caso sería `this`) en mayúsculas:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'mayusculas', {
  get() {
    return this.toUpperCase();
  }
});

const str = "string";
const str1 = "StRiNgStRiNg";

console.log(str.mayusculas);
console.log(str1.mayusculas);
console.log("Soy otra cadena de texto".mayusculas);
```